# Use ROSJava on Kinetic

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is anyone having any idea how to install rosjava api on kinetic. I followed the documentation http://wiki.ros.org/rosjava/Tutorials/kinetic/Source%20Installation    but I am getting stuck in the step "catkin_make". Its showing some error :
CMake Error at rosjava_build_tools/CMakeLists.txt:49 (file):
file failed to open for writing (Permission denied):

```
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/maven/rospack_nosubdirs
```

Any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265001/use-rosjava-on-kinetic/) by [shantanu543](https://answers.ros.org/users/30523/shantanu543/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-06-28

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@shantanu543 are you installing from debians or from source? Try going for the source installation, it's not that hard to do and perhaps it will save you some trouble. Remember to source the workspace that you used to build `rosjava` whenever you want to create or build your own projects.

---

Originally posted by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) with karma: 1054 on 2017-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Go to that path

```
cd /opt/ros/kinetic/share/maven/
```

then give full permission to the file. (777=rwxrwxrwx "no restrictions")

```
sudo chmod 777 rospack_nosubdirs
```

---

Originally posted by [Ostantric](https://answers.ros.org/users/31064/ostantric/) with karma: 21 on 2017-07-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2